# Is it possible to automatically serve correct dimension image on retina displays?

Tags: css, html

Seems like on Retina displays we are required to serve 2x images and then specify the dimensions as half width and half height. This is kind of annoying because you have to A) Look up the dimensions of the image then B) manually type in the 50% amount for the width and the height so that it doesn't show as double size.

I'm fine serving images which are twice the resolution but is there a faster easier way for specifying the dimensions they should actually be displayed at?

Comment: Check this out: [http://room118solutions.com/2012/04/28/server-side-retina-graphics/](http://room118solutions.com/2012/04/28/server-side-retina-graphics/) and this [http://shauninman.com/tmp/retina/](http://shauninman.com/tmp/retina/)

Comment: using css media queries might help --- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: Might be worthwhile checking out: http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/ too

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to set something in your `<head>` (before anything else) that writes a cookie that'll be sent to the server with all requests.

Something like this:

```
if((window.devicePixelRatio===undefined?1:window.devicePixelRatio)>1) document.cookie='HTTP_IS_RETINA=1;path=/';
```

Then you need to read that cookie in your server and make a decision whether to serve the regular or the retina image.

You can use `mod rewrite` (`.htaccess`)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} HTTP_IS_RETINA [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !@2x
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ $1@2x.$2
    # if @2x isn't available fulfill the original request
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)@2x\.(gif|jpg|png)$ $1.$2
</IfModule>
```

Or interpret it elsewhere.

Sources:

- http://room118solutions.com/2012/04/28/server-side-retina-graphics/
- http://shauninman.com/tmp/retina/